# Client characteristics [JAVA]

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client

I am trying to write my first client-server program in java but as I am new there are a few things that got me really confused. 
Is there any way to give specific characteristics to the client? For example I want each client who connects to have an id and a sum of money that will be changed by the server. Is something like this possible? If so how?
Also, I want to put some commands from the clients in a queue in order to make sure they are served in the correct order. How can I do that if each client has its own thread? In what part of the code should I initialise the queue?

Comment: Use either java.rmi.dgc.VMID or java.rmi.server.UID to come up with a unique name you could send to the client during the initial handshake between the client and the server

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll look it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this :

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class GenerateUUID {

  public static final void main(String... aArgs){
    //generate random UUIDs
    UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
    UUID idTwo = UUID.randomUUID();
    log("UUID One: " + idOne);
    log("UUID Two: " + idTwo);
  }

  private static void log(Object aObject){
    System.out.println( String.valueOf(aObject) );
  }
}
```

Output:

```
UUID One: 067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00  
UUID Two: 54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9-9af509fb5889
```

For the queue, send the request in the order you want at the client side and handle the request the same way you sent them from each client to avoid Exceptions.Thus if I understand your second requirement very well.